# How to display a confirmation box when I click a checkbox inside a datatable in websphere jsf portlet without using java script

Tags: jsf, websphere, portlet

I am developing a websphere jsf portlet where I need to display a confirmation box when a check box inside dataTabale is clicked. All selected items will be updated in the database. I am avoiding pop up but since the user wants the program to be flexible enough to let them do the update in special occasions so all I can do is to double check with the user. But definitely w/o using javascript. I am using jsr 168 portlet and JSf 1.2 with IBM RAD 7.5

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, this one is simple: you can't. Without Javascript you can not react to anything else than sending a form (by clicking a button or - if there is only one text input - pressing enter) or clicking a link.

So unless you change the question - the answer is: what you want is impossible.